# IoT share file between apps

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, local-storage, windows-10-iot-core

I'm doing my first steps on Microsoft IoT on a Raspberry pi 3.
I was able to deploy and run the application.
However, I need to run two application, one is going to write a file with events, and the other is going to pick up the batch and send it to Azure.

I was wondering what file location/ path should I use, as the App path changes with every new build.

Should I develop as a single app instead?
Kind Regards,
Juan

Comment: What do you mean by "events"?

Comment: event, is not important, I'm saving stuff in a file, this files needs to be picked up by another program, so I need to use a share folder. I'm struggling to understand the directory structure of IoR

Comment: Yes, it is important, because a file may not be (and probably isn't) the right way of doing this.

Comment: What do you recommend?

Comment: Have you tried [KnownFolders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.knownfolders.aspx) ?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not able to change the permission on the folders, always getting an "Access Denied". I browse the file system, but not able to get permission neither. I'm going to try to store in SQLite and then somehow trigger the batch and send it to Azure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it fits your scenario, but sounds like the purpose of a second app is to pick up some parameters and send to Azure. So, maybe it's time to consider using [App Service.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service)

In general, App service is a background task that runs in the backgound, with on-time event triggers. You can pass in parameters when your app triggers the service, and gets return data when necessary.

If hope it helps.